# Delete all connections related to a specific query in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro that creates a Power Query and uses SQL to grab data, then transform it in Power Query and output the results into a new tab. The macro then converts the query table to a range, then deletes the query. I know I have probably over-complicated the process, but here's my question...

Whenever I delete the query, there's a blank connection that sticks around. Can anyone help with writing a macro that deletes all connections to the query, then deletes the query itself? I just want to retain the output information and nothing else. The query will always be called RSPL_Query.

I want to avoid any solution that deletes all queries or all connections. This macro will be used in various spreadsheets because it's part of an add-in, so I don't want to inadvertently delete someone else's queries.

I have tried the below, but I keep getting a run-time error (1004) - Application defined or object defined error.

```
Sub DeleteRSPLQueryConnections()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
    For Each cn In wb.Connections
        If cn.Type = xlConnectionTypeODBC And InStr(1, cn.ODBCConnection.Connection, "RSPL_Query", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            cn.Delete
        End If
    Next cn
    
End Sub
```

I have also tried multiple other iterations of the above, but almost always get an error or they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Two potential problems:

- when deleting from a collection (in your case `cn.connections`), you delete the first record, so the second record now becomes the first, however the code skips on to the next record.
- the error you report seems to be thrown by the section within the `Instr` function, specifically `cn.ODBCConnection.Connection`. Use <kbd>F8</kbd> to step through the code to this point, then use the locals window to check the different properties and values available to you and identify which one you need to be testing against.

The below solution solves only the first problem I've identified, not the second - but I hope the above is enough info for you to fix the rest yourself.

```vb
Sub DeleteRSPLQueryConnections()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Dim lConnectionNum As Long, cn As WorkbookConnection
For lConnectionNum = wb.Connections.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set cn = wb.Connections(lConnectionNum)
    If cn.Type = xlConnectionTypeODBC And InStr(1, cn.ODBCConnection.CommandText, "RSPL_Query", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        cn.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```